# Classifying nested 3-manifolds with fundamental group property

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, fundamental-group

Let $M_1\subseteq M_2\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be closed connected subsets with smooth boundary.  Suppose that every closed loop in $M_1$ is freely homotopic inside $M_2$ to a closed loop inside $M_2\setminus M_1^\circ$.  Equivalently, every element of $\pi_1(M_1)$ is conjugate inside $\pi_1(M_2)$ to an element in the image of $\pi_1(M_2\setminus M_1)\to\pi_1(M_2)$.  Also assume that the complements of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected (by Alexander's theorem this implies that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are both irreducible).  What can be said about $M_1$ and $M_2$ in this situation?

My goal here is to force $\pi_1(M_1)\to\pi_1(M_2)$ to be **zero**.  Unfortunately, this is not guaranteed in the situation above, since we could take $M_1=M_2$ to be a handlebody.  Indeed, any loop inside a handlebody can be pushed to its boundary (use general position to make it disjoint from a graph $G\subseteq M_1$ of which $M_1$ is a regular neighborhood).  But maybe this is "as bad as it gets"?

Without the assumption on the connectedness of $\mathbb R^3\setminus M_i$, there are more counterexamples such as $M_1=B(2)\setminus B(1)^\circ$ and $M_2=B(2)$, but I don't care much about this relaxation of the question.

The significance of the hypothesis that $M_2\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ (rather than just being any compact connected orientable irreducible three-manifold with boundary) is that I know it holds in the situation I am interested in.  It may be end up being irrelevant as far as the question asked is concerned.

Comment: The relevant result (I think, due to Peter Scott) is that if $M$ is a compact connected 3-manifold with boundary and  there is a boundary component $S$ such that every loop in $M$ is freely homotopic to $S$, then $M$ is a compression body with positive boundary equal to $S$.

Comment: It looks like the relevant reference is Harris--Scott's 1995 paper "Non-compact totally peripheral 3-manifolds" in the Pacific Journal, building on a 1985 paper of Brin--Johannson--Scott in the compact case.

Comment: So I guess this solves the case $M_1=M_2$.  What about the general case?

Comment: @JohnPardon: If a closed loop $\gamma$ is homotopic into $M_2-M_1$ then it's homotopic into $\partial M_1$, so the conclusion appears to be that $M_1$ is obtained from $M_2$ by gluing a compression body to a boundary component. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @HJRW: Homotopic into $M_2-M_1$ does not imply homotopic into $\partial M_1$.  For instance, take $M_2$ to be a ball and $M_1$ to be diffeomorphic to a nontrivial knot complement.

Comment: This also solves the problem in the case when the boundary of $M_1$ is incompressible. I am not sure about the general case.

Comment: @JohnPardon: You’re quite right, of course; $\gamma$ is homotopic into $\partial M_1$ in $M_2$, but not in $M_1$. I guess there’s a good chance that the BJS proof can be extended to give you what you want...

Comment: The question "What can be said about $M_1$ and $M_2$ in this situation?" is a bit vague.  What do you actually want to hold?

Comment: @SamNead One conjecture (assuming that both $M_1, M_2$ are compact connected irreducible manifolds) would be that either $\pi_1(M_1)\to \pi_1(M_2)$ is trivial  or $M_1$ is a compression body.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - That does not work...  Taking the "boundary connect sum of pairs" we can glue examples together.  May we add the assumption that $\partial M_2$ is incompressible in $M_2$?

Comment: @SamNead Yes, it's a good example. But maybe add "boundary irreducible"? Incompressible boundary as you suggested is another good assumption.